# Try to open the socket connection which is alreay opened hangs the android system.How to solve it?

Tags: android, sockets, mobile-application, android-2.2-froyo

I am very new to android. I am developing an application in android 2.2 that sends the some bytes to server via socket connection.

In server side they used simple java coding for server socket implementation. The sending data in socket connection is success.

But my problem is when send the data in socket connection then I close the connection in client side (that is in mobile side). But in server side it does not closed.

Then again the client try to send data to server via socket. So the client side (in android mobile) application is hanged.

```
socket=new Socket(this.ipAddress,this.port_number);
```

The above coding snippet hangs the client system. How to show the error screen in the client side without hanging client application.

All are welcome to give your ideas

Comment: considered a `try{}catch(Exception e){}` around the `Socket` creation?

Comment: Im putting this code inside try-catch block.My problem there is no any exception but system hangs for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution,The following are the steps,codings,etc.

```
while(//condition)   
{
  socket=new Socket(this.ipAddress,this.port_number);
     //Opening input and output streams
     //Transfer the data
     //After data transfer connectin is closed.
     //While loop runs untill some condition     
}
```